# cc.net add comment to build result

Tags: cruisecontrol.net

I want to add comment to build result, for example add of cause why build is failed.

Has cc.net this feature?

How i can set up my server for this?

Answer (score 0):

No, there's no in built feature to pause the build to accept a failure reason, or any other input, is provided.

You could:

1. Provide a build reason on the next build, e.g. "fixing previous build..."

   - This would use the askForABuildReason project configuration, however I'm not sure how well supported it is in the webdashboard/cctray.
2. If possible proved a more descriptive reason for the failure, e.g. a task which detects the number of test failures and adds it to the build log.

   - You could then add a control to the webdashboard to show this.

Although its retrospective I'm guessing that (1) would give you the most flexibility, in that you can enter a customized message.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

There is a mechanism for getting the users input, but I would not recommend that in this case.
You want to update an existing build, maybe hours after it broke, so if you really want it now, you could edit the build log file, and add a BuildFailureComment tag in it.
That file is just xml. For visualisation, you could update one of the xsl files.

If you want to have this feature included, best thing is to open an issue request.